# Load a range of arrays (C#)

Tags: c#, .net, arrays

I need to keep track of how many items are in a node of this one attribute in C# and I have no idea on how to load an array, starting with 1 and ending with a variable

The code for this portion is this

```
//Loads file containing OSXInstaller File List
doc.Load("Distribution.xml");
XmlNodeList ChoiceNode = doc.GetElementsByTagName("choice");
foreach (XmlNode choices in ChoiceNode)
{
    //Code Executed only  for packages, not categories
    if (choices.HasChildNodes == true)
    {
        choicetitle.Add(choices.Attributes["title"].InnerText);
        //Counts the number of items with an attribute of "title" in the 
        //distributions file, so if the user selects #1 in the list box it will 
        //know what number one is
        choicelistcount++;
    }
    if (choices.HasChildNodes == false)
    {
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Your Mac OS X Installation disk is damaged or was mounted improperly, please try again and doube-check your information!");
    }
}
```

I'm trying to get it to count the number of items with the attribute of title, then being able to print out all of the items in the list

**choicetitle is the string list**

I want it to look something like:

```
listBox1.Items.Add(choicetitle[1-choicetitlecount]);
```

edit: To answer some of the comments below;

I put this together in a very short time and things like spell-checking don't really matter to me

The reason why I also include an else statement is because it adds an additional check whether the OSX Install Disk was mounted

The Program is a tool to Add & Remove packages to the OSX Installer, not as in a live-cd type thing but to add packages that you can install onto your new OS X installation
website is at http://osxreformer.org

Comment: What type of object is `choicetitle`? Could we see a sample of the XML you're using?

Comment: You misspelled **double**.  What on earth are you writing?

Comment: Is choicetitle a collection, or just pseudocode for what you want to do?

Comment: Your code is a little unclear, and there are some problems with it, such as displaying an error when HasChildNodes is false. Could you take a look at it and make it a little clearer (and correcter) so that we can help out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is unclear, but you probably want to use the [`List<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19.aspx) class, which can hold any number of elements.

You can create a `List<SomeType>`, and then add as many `SomeType` objects to it as you want, without worrying about size or capacity. (unless you run out of memory)

Answer (score 0):

You need to loop through part of your list, like this:

```
for(int i = 1; i < choicetitlecount; i++)
    listBox1.Items.Add(choicetitle[i]);
```

Note that .Net arrays and collections are 0-based, so unless you want to skip the first item, you probably want to start at 0.  (change `int i = 1` to `int i = 0`)

---

In general, you should give meaningful names to your controls (except labels).  For example, you might want to rename `listBox1` to `choiceTitleList`.